Dependencias en cada proyecto que haga
Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y tenia una duda  ¿tengo que instalar el npm  el express o jest para cada proyecto nuevo que haga?

osea no hay manera de que ya se encuentre a "mano" por así decirlo listos para su uso... y no estar instalando cada rato...

Npm es un gestor de dependencias, por lo que ya queda instalado en el ordenador/pc que utilices y no es necesario que vuelvas a instalarlo.
Por otra parte, las dependencias tales como lo son express y jest, son necesarias para cada proyecto. Dado que, cuando inicializas un proyecto, es el equivalente a empezar a escribir en una hoja en blanco y necesitas declarar cuales son las herramientas que necesitas.
Podrías instalar esas dependencias de manera global ( ¡LO CUAL ES UNA MALA PRACTICA! ) utilizando el comando install con la flag -G ```npm install express -G``. Pero esto supondría que tendrías un package.json sin el listado de dependencias que has utilizado en el proyecto, llevando a un posible error en el código cuando intentes desplegarlo
